# Open webpage programmatically and retrieve its html contain as a string

Tags: c#, html

I have a facebook account and I would like to extract my friend's photo and its personal detail such as "Date of birth", "Studied at" and so on. I am able to extract the address of the facebook's first page for each of my friends account but I don't know how to programmatically open webpage for each of my friends first page and save the html contain as a string so that I can extract out their personal detail and photos. Please help! Thank in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html = new WebClient()
               .DownloadString("the facebook account url goes here");
```

Also, once you have downloaded the HTML as a string I would highly recommend that you use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse it.

Comment: Won't the request need to authenticate?

Comment: Hah, gotta love C where downloading a file requires 5+ lines and a library :)

Comment: @harpo - Not if the data on the page is public - the OP didn't say.

Comment: @Andrew As a side note, keep in mind that some sites will reject the request if you don't specify a user agent.  Your example will work for most sites, however I've seen a handful that will reject this request.

Comment: this is my url address "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100000851682124" when pass into the DownloadString method an exception is been throw out saying that URI formats are not supported.

Answer (score 9):

You have Three options:

1- **Using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx) object.**

```
WebClient webClient = new webClient();
webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName","Password", "Domain");
string pageHTML = WebClient .DownloadString("http://url");`
```

---

2- **Using a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.71).aspx). This is the best solution because it gives you more control over your request.**

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://URL");  
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();  
Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();                 
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"); 
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( ReceiveStream, encode ); 
string strResponse=readStream.ReadToEnd();                 
StreamWriter oSw=new StreamWriter(strFilePath);     
oSw.WriteLine(strResponse); 
oSw.Close(); 
readStream.Close();        
myWebResponse.Close();
```

---

3- **Using a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085(v=vs.85).aspx) (I bet you don't wanna do that)**

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("http://URL");
string pageHTML = "";
wb.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => pageHTML = wb.DocumentText;
```

Excuse me if I misstyped any code because I improvised it and I don't have a syntax checker to check its correctness. But I think it should be fine.

---

EDIT: For facebook pages. You may consider using facebook Graph API:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Here is a comparison of 2 of the 3 methods above: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/

Answer (score 4):

There are in general 2 things you can do here. The first thing you can do is called web scraping. That way you can download the source of the html with the following code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");

var response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
 string stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`stringResponse` then contains the Html source of the website `http://example.com`

However, this is probably not what you want to do. Facebook has an SDK that you can use to download this kind of information. You can read about this on the following pages

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

If you want to use the FaceBook API then I think it's worth changing your question or asking a new question about this, since it's quite more complicated and requires some autorization and other codings. However, it's the best way since it's unlikely that your code is every going to break and it warrents the privacy of the people you want to get information from.

For example, if you query me with the api, you get the following string:

```
{
   "id": "1089655429",
   "name": "Timo Willemsen",
   "birthday": "08/29/1989",
   "education": [
      {
         "school": {
            "id": "115091211836927",
            "name": "Stedelijk Gymnasium Arnhem"
         },
         "year": {
            "id": "127668947248449",
            "name": "2001"
         },
         "type": "High School"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can see that I'm Timo Wilemsen, 21 years old and studyied @ Stedelijk Gymnasium Arnhem in 2001.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium 2.0 for C#.  [http://seleniumhq.org/download/](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.0b2.zip)

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
String pageSource = driver.PageSource;
```