# How to check single IP address to know if it is IP camera address

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip-camera

**EDIT:** I do know how to access camera when I have its IP address. The question is how to check if the specified IP address in local network belongs to an IP camera.

---

I work in a small local network with one router. The Range of available addresses in that network is: 
from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`

There is an IP camera connected to that network. The address of that camera is: `192.168.0.12`.

I queried the router for its ARP table in command line by using the `arp -a` command. It is shown here (green color).

[image]

I discovered that address by *AXIS IP Utility*, but I would like to be able to do so programatically.

The camera model is: **Axis m1011w**

**EDIT2**: Thanks to OnoSendai I got the possible IP addresses pool from the router's ARP table:

[image]

**How do I query each one of the listed IP addresses (for example `192.168.0.12`) to make sure it is an IP camera?**

Comment: Does your camera have some sort of "handshake" protocol that it accepts?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's the stuff I do not know. I do not know how to send and what message to the IP address and what answer to expect. The camera is Axis m1011w. I looked through AXIS SDK: http://developer.axis.com/wiki/doku.php?id=axis:sdk  but did not find any function which would help. I feel like Alice in the Rabbit hole... lost.

Comment: It's pretty common for these sorts of cameras to expose a webpage or other protocol for external applications to detect and access their services. I'd recommend playing with telnet to identify which of the common ports are open and what sorts of messages they accept. This will provide the details around what your application needs to mimic to be able to detect the appropriate device at the IP (more information is better for reducing false positives).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'd expect some sort of UDP listening to be going on. Pinging each address in turn is not going to scale well.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe this model offers a HTTP RTSP service at port 554. You can try to open a TCP connection to it - if the device accepts the incoming connection, then it may be the camera.

If you have a proper username/password credential pair to access it, then you may access the RTSP service by using this URL:

```
rtsp://[username]:[password]@[ip.address]:554/axis-media/media.amp
```

Here's a link to their spec:

http://www.axis.com/en/products/cam_m1011w/index.htm

And here the access instructions:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?39

In order to list all IP addresses on your local network, you can read the information dumped by the ARP command by using this snippet:

```
    static List<string> GetARP()
    {
        List<string> _ret = new List<string>();

        Process netUtility = new Process();
        netUtility.StartInfo.FileName = "arp.exe";
        netUtility.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        netUtility.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a";
        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        netUtility.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        netUtility.Start();

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(netUtility.StandardOutput.BaseStream, netUtility.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding);

        string line = "";
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (line.StartsWith("  "))
            {
                var Itms = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (Itms.Length == 3)
                    _ret.Add(Itms[0]);
            }
        }

        streamReader.Close();

        return _ret;

    }
```

The function will return a `List<string>` containing all local IP addresses (as present at the router's ARP table).

Comment: I do know how to access camera when I have its' ip address. The problem is to detect the ip address programatically.

Comment: @Yoda Code snippet added.

Comment: Thanks I will check it as fast as I can my brain is little slow at 6:51 am and no sleep. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure thing, take your time - and hope it works for you.

Comment: It made getting ARP table possible(result in orignal post EDIT2). But now the problem is how to querry single ip address to somehow get to know if it is ip camera on the other side. I tried to ask AXIS help desk but the consultant wasn't too helpful or polite. He was using only single words instead of sentences and he said: Bonjour(no more). I do not know if it is helpfull in C#.

Comment: You may try to cycle through all entries returned by GetARP() programatically. Here's a nice post on how to do it using the WebClient and WebRequest classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736831/open-webpage-programmatically-and-retrieve-its-html-contain-as-a-string

Comment: Doing loop is simple, single querry/ask is a problem, thank you. I feel I must go to sleep its 7:29. Your last comment might be very helpfull(the link). I'll deal with it in few hours. I REALLY THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME : ).

Comment: It was a pleasure - and hope it works for you! It's 1:33 AM for me, so I'll be hitting the bed soon as well. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai - be cautious redirecting both stdout and stderr but only reading stdout synchronously.  The MSDN says to put at least one of them in an asynchronous read, but it is also OK to put both in asynchronous reads, then just wait for process to terminate.